# creating a TomCat 6.0 Web Application

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I am trying to create a small Java application using Tomcat and am having some trouble getting started. Are there any resources online that can point me in the right direction? I've tried http://www.online-etraining.com/creating-a-tomcat-web-application but it's saying to use version 5.x of TomCat. I am currently running Eclipse with TomCat 6.0 on a Windows 7 machine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sebastian

Comment: Have you tried creating the web app following the same procedure using Tomcat 6.x? Did you face any problems?

Comment: I did face issues during the compile process where it was searching for some packages that weren't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Eclipse Web Tools (WTP) 'Dynamic Web Project'

I've already covered how to set it up here -> 
[How do I properly deploy and structure projects in Eclipse against Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464910/how-do-i-properly-deploy-and-structure-projects-in-eclipse-against-tomcat/4465232#4465232)

It also talks about Tomcat 5.5, but that is because the OP there asked about that particular version.  It actually works the same with 6.0 and even 7.0

I've covered how to get WTP installed here -> [Integrating Tomcat7 and Eclipse Helios on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642776/integrating-tomcat7-and-eclipse-helios-on-snow-leopard/4642861#4642861)

Answer (score 0):

This is also just for tomcat 5, but the steps should be similar:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For my website, which is a Java Web App, I started of with http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/. Although, I'm not sure of you're planning to use MVC or not, but I highly recommend it.